# Why is my image layer rotating around the edge of the image and not the center?

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, catransform3drotate

I'm trying to rotate an image around the center of a view using sliders, one for x, y and Z planes. I would like the image to rotate inside it's framed boundaries (700X700) but for some reason it rotates around the edges of the frame. I tried resetting the anchor point but that doesn't seem to do anything. here's the code to rotate it around the Y axis; you'll notice the anchor point section commented out - it wasn't having any affect at all. Any idea of what i'm doing wrong?

```
     float angleYDeg = self.ySlider.value;
     float angleYRad = (angleYDeg / 180.0) * M_PI;

    // Disable Animation
     [CATransaction begin];
     [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                  forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];

 // Get Layers
     CALayer *containerLayer = [[self.imageView.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0];
     CALayer *holder = [containerLayer valueForKey:@"__holderLayer"];

     //CGPoint anchor = holder.anchorPoint;
     //anchor.y = self.imageView.frame.size.height/2;
     //holder.anchorPoint = anchor;

     // Update xAngle Value
     [containerLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:angleYRad] forKey:@"__angleY"];

    // Apply rotations
     CGFloat angleX = [[containerLayer valueForKey:@"__angleX"]floatValue];
     CATransform3D holderTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation( angleX, 1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f);
     holderTransform = CATransform3DRotate(holderTransform, angleYRad, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
     holder.transform = holderTransform;

     [CATransaction commit];

     // Update Label
     self.yValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4.0fº", angleYDeg];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the exact answer to your question as I can't figure out where it's going wrong in the code. By default things should be rotating around the center. I wrote a demo app that shows how to change the rotation for all the axis using a UISlider. I've posted it on github here: https://github.com/perlmunger/AllAxis.git . Here is the gist of the code, though:

```
- (IBAction)sliderDidChange:(id)sender
{
  [self setTransforms];
}

- (void)setTransforms
{
  CGFloat x = [_xSlider value];
  CGFloat y = [_ySlider value];
  CGFloat z = [_zSlider value];

  CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
  transform.m34 = 1.0f/-800.0f; // perspective

  CGFloat rotationValue = x * kRotationMaxInDegrees;

  transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, 
                  degreesToRadians(rotationValue), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

  rotationValue = y * kRotationMaxInDegrees;

  transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, 
                  degreesToRadians(rotationValue), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

  rotationValue = z * kRotationMaxInDegrees;

  transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, 
                  degreesToRadians(rotationValue), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

  [[_rotationView layer] setTransform:transform];

}
```

This code builds up a collective transform that you apply to the view's layer on each change to any slider.

Comment: this is perfect - exactly what I was looking for! Thank you Matt!

Answer (score 0):

Doing consecutive transforms can often go awry.  When you transform the angleX, the AngleY transform will then be executed based on the new coordinate system.  Basically all the transforms are done relative to the "model" or object.

Most people usually expect the transforms to be made relative to the camera system, or as we are looking at the view.  Its likely that the results you want are going to be obtained by reversing the order of the transforms like this:

```
// Apply rotations
 CGFloat angleX = [[containerLayer valueForKey:@"__angleX"]floatValue];
 CATransform3D holderTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation( angleYRad, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
 holderTransform = CATransform3DRotate(holderTransform, angleX, 1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f);
 holder.transform = holderTransform;

 [CATransaction commit];
```

It might help if you think of it as a lifo system (though its not!) if you are considering all moves based on camera coordinates instead of the model's coordinates.

Comment: that didn't make any different unfortunately... any other suggestions?

Comment: Actually, I'm wondering if I'm thinking about this entirely incorrectly. I want my image to rotate in place, and the diameter of the cicrle made by the rotation should be the width of the image. What is happening here is that it's rotating around the edge, making the diameter of the circle it makes TWICE the width of the image. Do I need to use a different kind of animation to just make it rotate in place?

Comment: Looking at your question more closely (sorry for not doing that sooner!!!) the anchor point doesn't affect a 3D transform.  The center of action is always 0,0,0.  So if its not rotating around the point you need to rotate around, you must do a translation transformation to move the point about which you want to rotate to the center of your model's coordinate system.  So-- translate, then rotate, then translate it to where you want it.  Those are the steps to get it to rotate around a different point.